# Post of properties in a nested list does not seem to work in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I have an Object with a main list in it and a sub list in that main list. Showing the properties in a form is no problem.
But when I post the form and one or more of the properties of the sub list are inputs (hidden or not) I get the following:

```
InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'groups[0].members[0]' of bean class [xxx.MyModelObject]: Index of out of bounds in property path 'members[0]'; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

I use a Freemarker (2.3.22) view. The generated html of one sub list property is:

```
<input type="hidden" id="groups0.members0.surName" name="groups[0].members[0].surName" value="dummyName">
```

Seems Ok to me. There is no problem with simple properties in the main list, like id groups0.groupName / name groups[0].groupName.
(spring version 4.1.3).

Comment: is `groups[0].members[0]` correctly initialized?

Comment: What do you mean with correctly initialized? The first row in the ArrayList wthin the first row of the first ArrayList contains an object that contains filled properties like the string dummyName you see in the question. In the controller I wrote a toString to the log and the log confirms it.

Comment: Check getters and setters forma group and member classes

Comment: Thanks Fran! I checked the getters and setters of the `Member` class and they were all OK. In the `Group` class they were also all there, but the getter for the List had no `<Member>` after List. I could hardly believe that this could have this effect, but after adding `<Member>`, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check getters and setters from group and member classes

Comment: I had omitted the type of Objects in the getter for the `Member` List in the `Group` class. So it had nothing to do with the list being nested, false alarm.